# Async RPC with callback over HTTP

Tags: http, go, rpc, json-rpc

I am in the process of designing an SDK (in Golang) with blocking functionality, which should be run asynchronously with the result being returned via a callback.

I have been playing with the [Gorilla Toolkit RPC library](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/rpc) which is great but I don't see a way of returning values of async calls.

Perhaps I am missing something and the RPC model does not support async calls, by that I mean all calls are blocking, even for a long time. If that is the case, i'm assuming there is no HTTP timeout then?

How can I implement async RPC calls with a return value being returned via a callback.

**For clarification:** I cannot use the typical Go Channel method for callbacks as I will be calling the RPC from another language over HTTP. So my question is, is there a way to implement callbacks over HTTP when doing RPC or should the calls just block, even for a long time until a value is ready to be returned?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Gorilla, but in the **net/rpc** package of the standard library of Go you'll find this method [net/rpc/Go](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#Client.Go). It makes a RPC call asynchronously, you give it a channel as parameter so you can retrieve the RPC reply when the Remote Procedure Call is finished.

[net/rpc/Call](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#Client.Call) also makes a RPC call but it is blocking until the call is finished. If you know how to use channels I'm sure you'll get what you want with the Go method.

Comment: Thanks for this. My issue is that I will be making RPC calls from other platforms (Java, Python etc) so need to know how to make callbacks over HTTP.. Or do the calls just block until a value is returned?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [grpc](http://www.grpc.io/docs/). This:

- Has a [native go implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go)
- Has a implementations for "Java, Python, etc" for most values of 'etc'
- Works over HTTP2 (OK, not quite http, but pretty similar)
- Is fully [asynchronous](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html) (example happens to be C++).

Comment: Interesting, can you tell me how it does callbacks? Is that a feature of HTTP2?

Comment: I'm not an expert on `grpc` but I think what it's doing is maintaining a single (or small pool) of HTTP2 connections through which it can concurrently make several requests. When the reply comes back from each request, it triggers the callback. IE the async nature is a product of 'more than one request in flight at once' and a nice library, rather than true server->client notifications.

Comment: Hmm, ok, sounds interesting. I wonder if the Gorilla toolkit operates similarly. I'll investigate further, thanks.